# Resolve missing server in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-4

I use netbeans 8.1 and glassfish 4.0.When I click persistence.xml-design tab,a warning appears like *The project does not have the target server properly.Java persistence features are server-dependent* ...
So I don't use JPQL on persistence.xml

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I click persistence.xml-design tab,a warning appears like The project does not have the target server properly.Java persistence features are server-dependent.Resolve missing server problem. But it has a server.So I do not use JPQL on persistence because of this warning.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: There is a warning message and it did not let to run any jpql.Any suggestion about this warnning message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for my QUESTION. If the project has a server, you will show your server to your ejb project. ejb projcet->properties->run and define your server.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem but with the little difference that mine was caused by attempting to downgrade glassfish from version 5.0.1 to 5.0. I had deployed my application using 5.0.1 but some issues with the jdbc drive occurred so I need to downgrade to Glassfish 5.0 and then this appears "The project does not have the target server properly... ", I checked the run properties and everything was all right.
In order to solve: first go to "project properties" and then to "Run" in the server option select  apply changes, restart netbeans, open again and change the server again to glassfish